# Why is nhibernate complaing about deleting this object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a few objects.

1. **Project** Object - this represents a basic project
2. **ProjectDependency** Object - this is mapping object that maps one project to another project (the dependent project).  See the nhibernate relationships:

here is the ProjectDependencies mapping class:

```
  public class ProjectDependencyMap
  {
      public ProjectDependencyMap()
      {
        References(x => x.Project).Not.Nullable().Fetch.Join();
        References(x =>.DependencyProject).Not.Nullable().Column("DependencyProjectId").Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

and here is the project map file:

```
public class ProjectMap
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.ProjectDependencies).AsBag().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);

        HasMany(x => x.ProjectDependentOf).KeyColumn("DependentProjectId").AsBag().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);

    }
}
```

normally this works fine but sometimes when i go to delete a project using:

```
 var project = Model.GetProject(id);
 Repository.Delete(project);
 Repository.Commit()
```

I get this error:

**deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[ProjectDependency#324]**

Can someone help clarify what the issue is here and if the way i am using the mapping above is incorrect

Comment: Try: `References(x => x.Project).Not.Nullable().Fetch.Join().LazyLoad();`

Comment: @George = that didn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I'm assuming that `Project.ProjectDependencies` is the other side of the `ProjectDependency.Project` relationship, not the `ProjectDependency.Dependent` relationship.  (now say that 3 times fast)

Consider the following objects:

```
var projectA = new Project();
var projectB = new Project();
var dep1 = new ProjectDependency
{
    Project = projectA,
    Dependent = projectB
};
projectA.ProjectDependencies.Add(dep1);
```

... and save them all to the database.  Now, let's delete one.

```
session.Delete(projectA);
```

Everything works fine.  NHibernate cascades the delete across the `ProjectDependencies` collection, so `projectA` and `dep1` are both deleted.  `projectB` is left in the database.

OK, let's reset.  Let's start over with `projectA`, `projectB`, and `dep1` in the database.  Additionally, let's add these:

```
var projectC = new Project();
var dep2 = new ProjectDependency
{
    Project = projectC,
    Dependent = projectA
};
projectC.ProjectDependencies.Add(dep2);
```

What happens when we delete `projectA` now?

```
session.Delete(projectA);
```

Everything tries to proceed as before.  `dep1` will be deleted by the cascade.  However, there's nothing there to clean up `dep2`, hence the error.  `dep2` still has a reference to `projectA`, which we are trying to delete.

The solution suggested by the error message is to clean up those relationships before trying to delete the entity.  However, how are you going to do this?  Starting from `projectA`, how do we find `dep2` and `projectC` to clean them up?

Two options:

- Execute a query: `session.Query<ProjectDependency>().Where(x => x.Dependent == projectA)`, then manually clean up the relationships.
- Add another collection to `Project`:

```
HasMany(x => x.DependentProjects)
    .KeyColumn("DependentProjectId")
    .AsBag()
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

... and then NHibernate would take care of the cleanup for you.

Comment: thanks Daniel.  I actually have your last suggestion already (see updated question) where i have this ProjectDependentOf property .  i didn't include it before because i didn't think it was material but i have added it now . . please advise.  Also can you clarity what you mean by "manually clean up the relationships"

Comment: the other issue is that i don't see any other projects that have a dependency to this project (like your example) so its unclear to me what is trying to hold to to the reference

Comment: any thoughts on my question in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the relationship is many-to-many and ProjectDependency is an entity that represents the join table, it's hard to tell from your question. I'm assuming tables:

Project ( ProjectId)

ProjectDependency (ProjectId, DependentProjectId) with foreign keys back to Project

To delete a Project record, you have to delete any ProjectDependency records that reference it. That means deleting the ProjectDependency records for which the Project is referenced by ProjectDependency.ProjectId and those referenced by ProjectDependency.DependentProjectId. To do this in code, you can simply remove the referenced entities from the collections. Since you're using the repository pattern, this operation should be implemented in the Delete method

```
public void Delete(Project project)
{
    using (var txn = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        project.ProjectDependencies.Clear();
        project.DependentDependentOf.Clear();
        _session.Delete(project);
        txn.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I though nhibernate will do this for me given the  mapping i have listed in the question with Cascase.DeleteOrphan?

Answer (score 1):

Showing Some code inside both method calls below would help :

```
Repository.Delete(project);
Repository.Commit();
```

But here are my 2 cents,

Remove the `.Inverse()` from the `ProjectDependencies` `HasMany` mapping.
If you want nhibernate to manage the state from the "one" side in a "one-to-many" relation-ship, you should not be using `.Inverse()` in the `HasMany` mapping.

So it becomes like this :

```
public class ProjectMap
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.ProjectDependencies).AsBag().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);

        HasMany(x => x.ProjectDependentOf).KeyColumn("DependentProjectId").AsBag().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.